$A \otimes J+ I \otimes B$ is prime ideal of $A \otimes B$.
Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^{\ast}-$ algebras and $A \otimes B$ denotes minimal(spatial) tensor product. Let $I$ and $J$ be prime ideals of $A$ and $B$ respectively. The following fact should be easy but I am  not able to see it.

$A \otimes J+ I \otimes B$ is prime ideal of $A \otimes B$.

It is clear that $A \otimes J+ I \otimes B$ is a closed ideal. Can someone please prove that it is infact a prime ideal.
